# phonegap android app cannot open camera

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to phonegap and am starting with phonegap 1.0.0 as the
iOS app is already being made using that version. I am using the same
code as the iOS app and am stuck on a problem.

Whenever I call the navigator.camera.getPicture method i get the error
below

While testing on Samsung Captivate and HTC Wildfire

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getPicture' of undefined at
file:///android_asset/www/js/profile_pic_settings_page.js:95

What seems to be the problem ? I searched everywhere and could not find
it. Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of questions:

1. Are you waiting for the "deviceready" event before calling navigator.camera.getPicture()?
2. Does the html page that loads "profile_pic_settings_page.js" also load phonegap-1.0.0.js?
3. Are you making sure you are using the Android version of phonegap-1.0.0.js?

Comment: For No. 1 
'$('#btn_upload_camera').bind('click', function() { 
 // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {  quality: 50
 });        }); '
This is what i have. 
Yes to both #2 and #3

Comment: Thanks for the reply... the third one was a no. I am using the android version of the js now.. and it works now.

Comment: I did not know there were different versions of js for iOS and android. Thank you.

Comment: hey man thanks for your answer, this worked for me :) +1 @Simon MacDonald